# ngroute pass different data for different id in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Main Web page, i have 2 different images.What i want to do is when i click on any of link images, it must load the same template but each link has different data to show on that template.On clicking the images it shows the template but how to insert different data for each link image.How should i do that as a beginner

**app.js**

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/inneralbum/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'inneralbum.html',
    controller:'MainCtrl'
})
```

**MainCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$params', function ($scope, $params) {
  $scope.id = $params.id;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have 2 options:

1. Using query parameters with your image id as query param
   Either you use the [ui-router funtionality](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) or you use angular's location service.
2. Using child-routes with one route for each image
   Please check the [ui-router docs on nested routes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) for that